# How do I center a div in another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1">
      <div id="div2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want div 2 to be in the center of div1 no matter what, no matther how much the div2 width changes. Atm the div2 only get centered of the containers width.
How can I do this? Is JS the last way to go?

Comment: hello, the Javascript is not Java :)

Comment: center tag? absolutely. this has been answered millions of times, please do some research thank yo

Comment: @m.antkowicz ops thank you haha. I always think javascript is the one who is popped up when it aint.

Comment: @Aziz <center> did not make it work

Comment: OK I did not suggest the center tag and the one who did apparently removed it, the center tag is ancient and deprecated. Tho I expected browsers to render it still....

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS flexbox does this with the `justify-content` and `align-items` attributes.

Style a class named something like `bullseye` as:

```
.bullseye {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   }
```

Then add the class to your `div1` element:

```
<div id=container>
   <div id=div1 class=bullseye>
      <div id=div2>
         This box is centered<br>
         horizontally and vertically.
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/1rd6tcra/

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 1):

You give the outer div a width and the inner one you give margin 0 auto.

```
#container{
width: 100px;
}

#div1{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Will this center vertically?

Answer (score 1):

check this code below

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1" style="width:100%;border:1px solid #F00;">
      <div id="div2" style="width:60%;border:1px solid #F0F;">
        here is my div2
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

make sure that your inner div has a certain width and it doesn't matter whatever the width of parent.

the css code is below

```
#div2{
  margin:auto;
}
```

you can check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dram/v20xhy8n/)

Comment: Will this center vertically?

Answer (score 1):

The modern way to do this is:

```
#div1 {
  position: relative:
}
#div2 {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```